# Blog CMS Ruby On Rails With Syndication

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a ruby  on rails CMS that can be used by journalists on the road to quickly write their article and upload media.

The resultant blog will be syndicated.

Can anybody think of such a ruby on rails cms that fits these needs?

Comment: try to look at the refinery cms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refinery CMS](http://refinerycms.com/) - good choice for non expert customers

[Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/) - is not so obvious for customers but simple